# Remove background from image

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to code a edge detector for images.

I am trying to detect the image in the frame like the following:

[image]

However, for cards it does not work:

[image]

As you can see it works perfectly for stickers, but NOT for cards.

I am using Canny from the `opencv` package.

```
# get image data
!curl -o icehockey.jpg https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/-9026717386575670185/4094320477310271395.jpg
!curl -o messi_card.jpg https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/-7936808709614507320/-7695734041040515044.jpg
!curl -o ronaldo_sticker.jpg https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/6559100964212657924/2938835010875297356.jpg
!curl -o kobe.jpg https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/3619951364396055589/2795941822594523503.jpg
!curl -o ronaldo_pr.jpg https://d1w8cc2yygc27j.cloudfront.net/-6264103397135568625/-373982158254483182.jpg

# install debugger
!pip install -Uqq ipdb

# import cv
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import ipdb
%pdb on


def get_new(old):
    new = np.ones(old.shape, np.uint8)
    cv2.bitwise_not(new,new)
    return new

def edgeDetection(img):
    orig = cv2.imread(img)

    # these constants are carefully picked
    MORPH = 9
    CANNY = 84
    HOUGH = 20

    img = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0, img)


    # this is to recognize white on white
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT,(MORPH,MORPH))
    dilated = cv2.dilate(img, kernel)

    edges = cv2.Canny(dilated, 0, CANNY, apertureSize=3)

    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1,  3.14/180, HOUGH)
    for line in lines[0]:
        cv2.line(edges, (line[0], line[1]), (line[2], line[3]),
                        (255,0,0), 2, 8)

    # finding contours
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                                  cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_TC89_KCOS)
    contours = filter(lambda cont: cv2.arcLength(cont, False) > 100, contours)
    contours = filter(lambda cont: cv2.contourArea(cont) > 10000, contours)

    # simplify contours down to polygons
    rects = []
    for cont in contours:
        rect = cv2.approxPolyDP(cont, 40, True).copy().reshape(-1, 2)
        rects.append(rect)

    # that's basically it
    cv2.drawContours(orig, rects,-1,(0,255,0),1)

    # show only contours
    new = get_new(img)
    cv2.drawContours(new, rects,-1,(0,255,0),1)
    cv2.GaussianBlur(new, (9,9), 0, new)
    new = cv2.Canny(new, 0, CANNY, apertureSize=3)

    # Does not work as it needs an x-server
    print("Original:")
    cv2_imshow(orig)
    print("Dilated:")
    cv2_imshow(dilated)
    print("Edges:")
    cv2_imshow(edges)
    print("New:")
    cv2_imshow(new)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


# run script
edgeDetection("./icehockey.jpg") # does NOT work
edgeDetection("./messi_card.jpg") # does NOT work
edgeDetection("./ronaldo_sticker.jpg") # does work
edgeDetection("./kobe.jpg") # does NOT work
edgeDetection("./ronaldo_pr.jpg") # does NOT work
```

My challenge is that I can detect the edges for stickers, BUT not for cards.

Find below an example of the colab sheet I have put my code on: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19QFI1R88qafVj8EBB9IFiwa1ESCyumuq?usp=sharing)

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the canny-algorithm work for cards?

Comment: I don't get you want to achieve. Do you want to detect the edges of the stickers or the card (stickers + plastic)?

Comment: @TsunamiSerra I want to detect the edges of the sticker and the card. For stickers it works better. For cards I am currently struggeling.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't care if it's a card or a sticker. I don't know the details, but it probably cares about the contrast between the parts you want to separate, which is smaller in the second image than in the first image.

Comment: Understood. However I would like to improve my accuracy for cards. Any suggestions?